# How to SELECT a.* FROM a WHERE EXCEPT SELECT b.* FROM b WHERE a.id != b.id

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am having quite a struggle with the presented postgres request.

I have a table **objects** with a few columns, including an id column.
I have a table **object_couples** that references couples of objects with id. This table contains in consequence 2 columns of ids.

I have an external variable, like `int external_variable = 42`.

I am trying to select every entry of the **objects** table where the **id** of the selected object and the id of the **external_variable** does not exist as a couple in the **object_couples** table.

My request looks like the following :

```sql
SELECT id, c1, c2 
    FROM objects 
    WHERE condition1 AND condition2 
EXCEPT SELECT left_id, right_id 
    FROM object_couples 
    WHERE objects.id != object_couples.left_id 
        AND external_variable != object_couples.right_id;
```

What can I do?

**EDIT 1 :**
The following request is not rejected but causes in pycharm a code 137(SIGKILL) :

````sql
SELECT id, c1, c2
   FROM objects AS S 
INNER JOIN object_couples 
   ON object_couples.left_id != S.id 
      AND object_couples.right_id != external_variable
WHERE S.c1 > 1234 AND S.c2 < 5678```
````

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from objects o
where not exists (select 1
                  from object_couples oc
                  where (oc.id = oc.left and 42 = oc.right) or
                        (oc.id = oc.right and 42 = oc.left)
                 );
```

For performance, you might find that this works better:

```
select o.*
from objects o
where not exists (select 1
                  from object_couples oc
                  where oc.id = oc.left and 42 = oc.right
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from object_couples oc
                  where oc.id = oc.right and 42 = oc.left
                 );
```

In particular if you have indexes on `object_couples(left, right)` and `object_couples(right, left)` then this might even be fast.

Comment: I will implement your contribution and try to make it work. Thanks a lot, i'll keep you updated.

Comment: The first request worked yesterday. I'll try the second one because I in deed faced some nice 10 seconds delay in its execution sometimes !